# Exception Handling for user input length

Tags: java, exception

I have a small ATM program and I am using Exception Handling on it. I have a try catch at the start of my program that is going to send it down to the Exception Handling - at the bottom of the program.

The user is suppose to enter a 5 digit number... example: 12345.
Then it goes to check the number and I have it checking if the users number is < 5 then send the error but what I want it to do is check if the length is < or > than 5 then send the error. This is my code right now for my program...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class BankMain
    {
    private double availableBal =80;
    private double totalBal =100;
    private double availableBal2 =480;
    private double totalBal2 =500;
    private double availableBal3 =80;
    private double totalBal3 =100;
    ArrayList<Integer> cardNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    private String error;           //String the error from the exception
    {
        error = "error";
    }


    public void cardNumbers(){


            Scanner cards = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);





            try{


            System.out.println("Please select a 5 digit card number");

            cardNum.add(input.nextInt());
            checkNumber();


            }

            catch(invalidNumber err){

                System.out.println("Caught Error: " + err.getError());
            }

            System.out.println("Thank you! You're card number is " +cardNum);

            System.out.println("Type 'c' to go back to main menu.");
            String value = keyboard.next();

            if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
                menu();

    }

    else if (!keyboard.equals('c')){

        System.out.println("Invalid Entry!");

    }

}


    public void menu(){

    System.out.println("ATM Menu:");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1 = Create Account");
    System.out.println("2 = Account Login");
    System.out.println("3 = Exit ATM");
    query();
                }

        public void startAtm()
        {
            menu();

        }



        public void drawMainMenu()
        {

            AccountMain main3 = new AccountMain();
            int selection;

            System.out.println("\nATM main menu:");
            System.out.println("1 - View account balance");
            System.out.println("2 - Withdraw funds");
            System.out.println("3 - Add funds");
            System.out.println("4 - Back to Account Menu");
            System.out.println("5 - Terminate transaction");
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            selection =input.nextInt();

            switch(selection)
            {
            case 1:
                viewAccountInfo();
                break;
            case 2:
                withdraw();
                break;
            case 3:
                addFunds();
                break;
            case 4:
                AccountMain.selectAccount();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Thank you for using this ATM!!! goodbye");
            }
        }

        public void viewAccountInfo()
        {
            System.out.println("Account Information:");
            System.out.println("\t--Total balance: $"+totalBal);
            System.out.println("\t--Available balance: $"+availableBal);
            drawMainMenu();
        }

        public void viewAccountInfo2()
        {
            System.out.println("Account Information:");
            System.out.println("\t--Total balance: $"+totalBal2);
            System.out.println("\t--Available balance: $"+availableBal2);
            drawMainMenu();
        }

        public void deposit(int depAmount)
        {
            System.out.println("\n***Please insert your money now...***");
            totalBal =totalBal +depAmount;
            availableBal =availableBal +depAmount;
        }

        public void checkNsf(int withdrawAmount)
        {
            if(totalBal -withdrawAmount < 0)
                System.out.println("\n***ERROR!!! Insufficient funds in you accout***");
            else
            {
                totalBal =totalBal -withdrawAmount;
                availableBal =availableBal -withdrawAmount;
                System.out.println("\n***Please take your money now...***");
                }
        }

        public void addFunds()
        {
            int addSelection;

            System.out.println("Deposit funds:");
            System.out.println("1 - $20");
            System.out.println("2 - $40");
            System.out.println("3 - $60");
            System.out.println("4 - $100");
            System.out.println("5 - Back to main menu");
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            addSelection =input.nextInt();

            switch(addSelection)
            {
            case 1:
                deposit(20);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 2:
                deposit(40);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 3:
                deposit(60);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 4:
                deposit(100);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 5:
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            }
        }

        public void withdraw()
        {
            int withdrawSelection;

            System.out.println("Withdraw money:");
            System.out.println("1 - $20");
            System.out.println("2 - $40");
            System.out.println("3 - $60");
            System.out.println("4 - $100");
            System.out.println("5 - Back to main menu");
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            withdrawSelection =input.nextInt();

            switch(withdrawSelection)
            {
            case 1:
                checkNsf(20);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 2:
                checkNsf(40);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 3:
                checkNsf(60);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 4:
                checkNsf(100);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 5:
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            }
        }

public void query(){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double input = keyboard.nextInt();  


    if (input == 2){

        BankMainPart2 main2 = new BankMainPart2();

        System.out.println("Please enter your 5 digit card number.");
         BankMainPart2.loginCard(cardNum);



    }
    else if (input == 1){

        cardNumbers();

    }

    else if (input == 3){
        System.out.println("Thank you, have a nice day!");
        System.exit(0);


    }

}

public void checkingMenu()
{

    AccountMain main3 = new AccountMain();
    int selection;

    System.out.println("\nATM main menu:");
    System.out.println("1 - View account balance");
    System.out.println("2 - Withdraw funds");
    System.out.println("3 - Add funds");
    System.out.println("4 - Back to Account Menu");
    System.out.println("5 - Terminate transaction");
    System.out.print("Choice: ");
    selection =input.nextInt();

    switch(selection)
    {
    case 1:
        viewAccountInfo2();
        break;
    case 2:
        withdraw();
        break;
    case 3:
        addFunds();
        break;
    case 4:
        AccountMain.selectAccount();
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Thank you for using this ATM!!! goodbye");
    }
}

private static void checkNumber() throws invalidNumber              //run the check activation exception
{
    if(input.nextInt() == 5)
  {
        System.out.println("Works!");
  }
    else{

     throw new invalidNumber("invalid number");
 }  
}

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BankMain myAtm = new BankMain();
        myAtm.startAtm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert number to String and then use `length()` to check the number of digits

Comment: thanks for the reply, sorry I'm new to java and I'm not sure exactly how to do that

Comment: Use [`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29)

Comment: String.valueOf(yourIntVariable).length()!=5{raise exception}

Answer (score 1):

As it is, your program should hang (you are not specifying this in your question so my assumption might be incorrect). You are calling `input.nextInt()` twice, which will make your program expect two sets of digits from your user.

To go around this, I would recommend that your first read the input of the user as a string, using the `nextLine()` method. Then, you will do something like so:

```
String userInput = input.nextLine().trim();
checkNumber(userInput);
cardNum.add(Integer.parseInt(userInput);
```

Also, the `checkNumber`, as is, will fail since we are now reading the entire line, so you will have to make the following changes:

- You will have to iterate over your characters and use the [`isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) to make sure that each of your characters is a digit   **OR**
- User a regular expression of the sort `^\\d{5}$` to make sure that the string is made up entirely from 5 numbers. For regular expressions, you can take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) tutorial to get you on the right track. If you are a beginner, this might seem a bit overwhelming but regular expressions are *usually* recommended to do data validation on strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
        System.out.println("Please select a 5 digit card number");

        String s=input.next();

        //Here check the nu. digits by using length()

        cardNum.add(s);

        checkNumber();
```

Comment: alright I did all this and now I use s.length() == 5 at the bottom but it wont read the string s .

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the entire code then check it length if its == 5 or not, you will need to convert the input to string using:

```
String.valueOf(int i)
```

or

```
Integer.toString(int i)
```

or just read it as string using:

```
string givenCode = yourScan.next();
```

then check the length:

```
if (givenCode.length() == 5)
```